# Can I store an array which contains a model and number in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to mongodb and mongoose and I wanted to know if it was possible for a schema to store an array which contains a model along with a number.

I have an item model as follows:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var Schema = mongoose.Schema

var item = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    price: {type: Number, required: true},
    date: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
})


module.exports = mongoose.model('Item', item)
```

And I have an Account model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var Schema = mongoose.Schema
var ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId

var account = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    id: {type: Number, required: true},
    ph_no: String,
    items: [[{type: ObjectId, ref: 'Item'}, {type: Number, default: 1}]]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Account', account)
```

In the account model, I want the "items" parameter to store an array of the item model and a number which refers to the quantity of the item.
Please let me know if this is possible or is this even an ideal model and whether I should I change it or not.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Just make the type of item in accout Schema to items Model

`var itemModel = require(<your_item_model>)`

```
var account = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    id: {type: Number, required: true},
    ph_no: String,
    items: [itemModel]
})
```